# Don't require external param name in enum associated value

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have an `enum`:

```
enum TextFieldRule {
    case MinLength(length: Int)
    case MaxLength(length: Int)
    case MatchesOtherTextField(textField: UITextField)
}
```

which could be called as:

```
.MinLength(length: 1)
```

Is there a way to make the external param name not required? So something like:

```
enum TextFieldRule {
    case MinLength(_ length: Int)
    case MaxLength(_ length: Int)
    case MatchesOtherTextField(_ textField: UITextField)
}
```

and called with:

```
.MinLength(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

param name is not required

```
enum TextFieldRule {
    case MinLength(Int)
    case MaxLength(Int)
    case MatchesOtherTextField(UITextField)
}

let rule = TextFieldRule.MinLength(1)

switch rule {
case .MinLength(let length):
    break
case .MaxLength(let length):
    break
case .MatchesOtherTextField(let textField):
    break
}
```

Comment: Wow no idea how this didn't occur to me as an option. Thanks, will accept.